# Print raw html text containing PLC printer commands?

Tags: php, html, printing

I'm opening a file in PHP with `file_get_contents()` and rendering into HTML between `<pre>` tags.

That file contains [PLC commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_Command_Language) which are old printer commands containing control ascii chars to make the text bold, larger, etc., like this:
`NETOS: (s8H   23.894,96&k2S(s4099T(s0B`

Are those commands conserved when rendered on html if you wish to print the html page?

Comment: If you are putting text in <pre> tags, the text will be shown on the web page, and printed as the text if you print. It will not be interpreted in any special way by a printer.

Comment: should I scrap those commands and convert them into what they've used to do?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PLC commands but if I am understanding what you are trying to do, that seems like a reasonable idea, if you know how to translate them into equivalent HTML.